# Max OS X terminal - проблема с русскими буквами при работе с Ubuntu 14.04 по ssh

Tags: ubuntu, macos, кодировка, terminal

В терминале OS X можно нормально печатать русскими буквами.
Но при подключении по ssh к Ubuntu 14.04 на удаленном сервере с русскими буквами возникает проблема (какие-то отображаются, какие-то не вводятся, вместо каких-то при вводе появляется бред).

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: на каждой OS своя кодировка. В dos одна, в windows другая, в linux третья, в mac тоже отличная от других. Надо привести терминал и сервер к общему стандарту.

Comment: Задам вопрос более конкретно: как решить проблему? (Куда лезть, что устанавливать.)

Comment: Посмотреть какие есть возможности по установке кодировок в Вашем терминале. Например в PuTTY для Windows можно указать кодировку удаленной системы и он сам транслирует её в windows. Спросить в гугле. Не первый же, кто сталкивается с такой проблемой.

Comment: Там есть комманда locale?

Comment: Да, но всякие команды вроде dpkg-reconfitgure locales не помогали. Проблема вроде бы решилась через sudo sh -c "echo 'LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8\nLANG=en_US.UTF-8' >> /etc/environment"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблему решил через

> sudo sh -c "echo 'LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8\nLANG=en_US.UTF-8' >> /etc/environment"

на сервере